# Replacing unwrap() with ? made code more complicated instead of simplifying it

Tags: rust, unwrap

This code deletes PNG files in a folder and prints them. I wanted to simplify it a bit by replacing all the `unwrap()`'s with `?`.

```
use std::fs;
use std::path::Path;

fn main() -> Result<(), std::io::Error> {
    let path = Path::new("/home/alex/Desktop");
    for entry in fs::read_dir(path)? {
        let entry = entry?;
        let path = entry.path();
        if path.is_file() && path.extension().unwrap() == "png" {
            fs::remove_file(&path)?;
            println!("{}", path.file_name().unwrap().to_str().unwrap());
        }
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

I found out I can't replace the `unwrap()`'s that are handling `Option` instead of `Result`. In this case, `extension()`, `file_name()`, and `to_str()`.

I changed the code to solve that problem. However, the code just became more complicated:

```
use std::fs;
use std::path::Path;

fn main() -> Result<(), std::io::Error> {
let path = Path::new("/home/alex/Desktop");
for entry in fs::read_dir(path)? {
    let entry = entry?;
    let path = entry.path();
    if path.is_file() {
        let ext = path.extension().ok_or(std::io::Error::new(std::io::ErrorKind::Other, "Invalid file extension"))?;
        if ext == "png" {
            fs::remove_file(&path)?;
            println!("{}", path.file_name().ok_or(std::io::Error::new(std::io::ErrorKind::Other, "Invalid file name"))?.to_str().ok_or(std::io::Error::new(std::io::ErrorKind::Other, "Invalid file name"))?);
        }
    }
}
Ok(())}
```

How to replace the `unwrap()`'s that are handling `Option` without making the code more complicated (especially, without so much nesting)? Or at least not as complicated as the one I shared?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In many of the cases where you were calling `unwrap` it wasn't actually an error, you just want to do something different (or not at all).

If you're only interested in the case where there is a `png` extension, check if that's what you got. It doesn't matter if it's `None` or `.jpg`.

Printing a filename can fail because filenames can have non unicode characters and Rust strings can't. In this case given it's presumably meant to be human readable, printing the `to_string_lossy()` output (replacing non-unicode characters) or printing it using debug mode (escaping non-unicode characters) is probably fine.

```
use std::fs;
use std::path::Path;

fn main() -> Result<(), std::io::Error> {
    let path = Path::new("/home/alex/Desktop");
    for entry in fs::read_dir(path)? {
        let entry = entry?;
        let path = entry.path();
        if path.is_file() {
            if let Some(ext) = path.extension() {
                if ext == "png" {
                    fs::remove_file(&path)?;
                    // I would keep expect here as extension would return None if there was no filename
                    // to_string_lossy returns a printable string - possibly replacing non-unicode characters
                    println!("{}", path.file_name().expect("File has no name").to_string_lossy());
                }
            }
        }
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the sample code, but it won't compile: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=35704d2e4f6fc374b6858731b1938cd3

Comment: Sorry, that's what I get for trying to program in the answer box and not testing it first. Should be fixed now

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll study your code in detail (I'm a Rust beginner).